# Non-Asymptotic Confidence Interval and Hypothesis Testing in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I need to calculate the 95% non-asymptotic confidence interval for the estimate of slope $\beta_1$ as well as to test the following hypothesis:

$H_0 : \beta_1=0$ and $H_1 : \beta_1\neq0$ i.e. to answer based on the obtained CI whether the slope is significant.
This is what I have done so far. The problem is that by default `confint` assumes asymptotic normality and I am not sure how to proceed from there.

```
attach(cars)
cars.lm <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
summary(cars.lm)
interval = confint(cars.lm, 'speed', level=0.95)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the confidence interval provided by `confint` with a linear model is not asymptotic by default (see documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/confint)). We can double check by computing a CI by hand with the summary output:

```
> set.seed(05122018)
> N <- 100
> x <- seq(1,100)
> y <- 2 * x + rnorm(N,0,35)
> my.lm <- lm(y ~ x)
> summary(my.lm)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-87.853 -29.471  -2.367  23.640 112.731 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.1151     7.7325   0.144    0.886    
x             2.0100     0.1329  15.121   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 38.37 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:    0.7, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6969 
F-statistic: 228.6 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> lb <- 2.01 + (qt(0.025, df=N-2) * 0.1329)
> ub <- 2.01 + (qt(0.975, df=N-2) * 0.1329)
> cat("Our interval [",lb,",",ub,"]\n")
Our interval [ 1.746264 , 2.273736 ]
> confint(my.lm)
                 2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) -14.229759 16.459910
x             1.746228  2.273834
>
```

which is the same out to the 4th or 5th decimal place. Also, it's a good idea in general to examine the model assumptions before performing inference.